# Glassfish 4: jmx service url contains router name? How to change it?

Tags: rmi, jmx, glassfish-4

How can the JMX service url be changed on glassfish 4?

The problem is the invalid character in the url which strangely consists of the *name of the router* containing underscores `_`.

How can this be changed to localhost for instance?

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: Bad URL path: _W_724V:4086/jndi/rmi://ComputerName.RouterName_W_724V:4086/jmxrmi
    at javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL.validate(JMXServiceURL.java:406)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL.validate(JMXServiceURL.java:411)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL.<init>(JMXServiceURL.java:226)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.RMIConnectorStarter.start(RMIConnectorStarter.java:287)
```

Other glassfish listeners are binded to the corrent local computer name url:

```
Information: Webservice Endpoint deployed ParticipantPortTypePortImpl 
    listening at address at http://ComputerName:4080/__wstx-services/ParticipantPortType11.
```

**Or why is on this computer the router name appended to the computer name in the JMX service?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

To fix this behaviour you have to set the primary DNS suffix of your Computer.

Then the url will look like "ComputerName.DNSSuffix".

For Win7:

Open "Control Panel" -> "System".

Next to your computer name click "Change Settings".

Next click "Change" and finally on "More".

Here you have to enter a valid name.

Restart Computer.

gr33tz